# Clarification and proof involving the Approximation Property for Suprema

Tags: real-analysis

$Sup(E) - \epsilon \lt a \leq Sup(E)$ where $\epsilon$ is any number greater than zero and $a \in E$

If I understand this correctly it is saying that there is always an element in the set that falls between the supremum and the supremum minus some positive number *no matter how big or small that number is*. If it is very small it equals the suprema itself. If it is sufficiently large then it could be another element a of the set. It is proved by contra-positive if I am understanding this correctly an $\epsilon$ is chosen so that no element in $A$ falls between the two. This suggests then that the element $a$ must be less than or equal to $Sup(E) - \epsilon_0$ then we use this fact to show $sup(E)$ is actually not the supremum and with some algebra arrive to a contradiction with $\epsilon$

I tried to do this with an exercise in the book. Show that if $E$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, then $inf(E)$ exists and it belongs to $E$ So i tried to use approximation property to show that inf(E) belongs to $E$ i.e $\mathbb{Z}$

Choose an $x_0$ such that
let $i=infimum(E)$ then we have:

Since it is an infimum it should look like: 
$i \leq x_0 \lt i + 1$ Well if $x_0 = i$ then we are done

$i \lt x_0 \lt i + 1$

$i \lt x_1 \lt x_0$ Through some manipulation we get:

$i - x_0 \lt x_1 - x_0 \lt 0$ and $-x_0 \gt -i-1$

but something is off here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb Z$ with infimum $i$. Then by the infimum approximation property with $\varepsilon=1$, there exists $a \in E$ such that

$$ i \leq a < i + 1 $$

Note that $a$ is unique, since the interval $[i, i+1)$ has length $1$ (with only one endpoint) so it must contain exactly one integer. We want to show $i=a$. Suppose for a contradiction $i<a$. Then, we can choose $\varepsilon < a-i$ so that

$$ i < i + \varepsilon < a < i + 1 $$

which implies $a \notin [i, i+\varepsilon)$. But since $a$ is the only integer in $[i,i+1)$, this gives

$$ [i, i+\epsilon) \cap \Bbb Z = \emptyset $$

which violates the approximation property.

Comment: Okay I understand that now why am I having problems applying the same idea to prove the infimum belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh, I edited my post with the answer to your real question.